# How do I insert the Guest Additions virtual image in an Ubuntu virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, fullscreen

The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Unable to insert the virtual optical disk C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the machine ubuntunodebox.  
Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED). 
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) 
Component: ConsoleWrap 
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} 
Callee: IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

I'm using Windows 10 as my machine's OS. I've installed Oracle Virtual Box, downloaded and installed Ubuntu 22.04, and I cannot make it display full screen. In the VirtualBox window, I click Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image... and a CD icon appears on my taskbar, however nothing runs. I clicked into the CD icon, click Run software, a spinning wheel appears, disappears, and nothing seems to have happened.

I feel stuck.

Comment: Is your question really "how do I insert the Guest Additions virtual image in an Ubuntu virtual machine"? If so, please edit the title and question text to focus on the actual question.

Comment: If this error occurs when you're trying to `mount` the virtual CD, it's likely because it's already automounted - type `ls /media/$USER` to see

Comment: Updated the title of post.

Comment: command ls /media/$USER does populate the virtual image as a result.

does this imply its automounted, and if it is, how then can I fix the display to full screen?

Comment: 3 things 1) you said "full screen", you didnt say resolution? So try "Scaled mode" and stretch the screen to fill your monitor. Instead of "Devices", go to "View", there is a "full screen" there too but it might not be what you want. 2) Dont "click the icon and run it from the taskbar", open a terminal and cd into the directory /media/username/VBoxGuxxx and run `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, that way you can see if it is completing. 3) If it successfully runs, reboot the VM and then see if you have desirable resolutions to choose from. But either way 2) and 3) dont fix "full screen", 1) does